# Anchor <a> tags not working in chrome when using #

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

Here is the code I am using on my page,

```
<li><a href="/explore/#Sound">Sound</a></li>
```

(in a menu which appears on all pages)

```
<a id="Sound"><a>
```

(on the page where i want to link to)

I have tried adding content to the tags with an id. But only in chrome the browser will not scroll down to the tag. These anchors work in IE&FF
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link to the page please?

Comment: https://dev.phonaudio.com/explore/#Sound

Comment: It need authentication. Can you do a JSFiddle?

Comment: Oh, of course my bad, yes i will

Comment: Although it will not work properly in jsfiddle as the problem is when i go from another page to this one, if i'm already on the page the # works

Comment: Are there any plugins in use which could be causing the issue?

Comment: I don't think so, i have removed authentication temporarily so you can look now :)

Comment: Cheers. It loaded on an older version of chrome, but doesn't work on 51.0.2704.106 on iMac. Have you checked to see if anyone has reported any bugs at Chromium?

Comment: I am on 52.0.2743.82 on a mac, but the client has reported it not working on a windows machine as well (not sure which version of chrome)

Comment: And after looking on chromium, I have found a solution :)

Comment: Oh cool, what was it? Fancy popping a link here? :)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-discuss/anchor/chromium-discuss/RAyinspmQyA/tQlGfgbOgvwJ  -  workaround from Alexey Breslavsky

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in certain versions of chrome, posting workaround for anyone who needs it! :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if (window.location.hash && isChrome) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                window.location.hash = "";
                window.location.hash = hash;
            }, 300);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate, well done on finding a solution. Got there in the end!

Comment: No problem at all! Normally a process of elimination will get you there!

Comment: Thanks @Jake_ for letting us know of such a bug... `:)`

Comment: Works well in Google Tag Manager too.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't fix the issue at all. and in Wordpress because of noConflict you cant use $ but jQuery

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jQuery? I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: `window.onload =` (same stuff here as is wrapped in ready function above) or if you want to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {alert("good")});`

Comment: Guys which file of my wordpress-website should I edit and add this code? My anchor-links are on the frontpage. Should I add that code on frontpage's html?

Comment: This doesn't work if you're navigating to a tag on the same page.

Comment: This will affect the browser's history. I've used `window.location.replace(hash)` the problem fixed.

Answer (score 36):

The workaround posted didn't work for me, however after days of searching this finally worked like a charm so I figured it was worth sharing:

```
 $(function() {
       $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
         if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
           var target = $(this.hash);
           target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: target.offset().top
             }, 1000);
             return false;
           }
         }
       });
     });
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me but this answer did. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also fix the same issue on Safari iOSX and Mac OSX

Answer (score 7):

If you somehow ended up here like me when finding out the anchor link to a SPA site doesn't work from an external site. Yep, the browser is just working too fast to load the skeleton of the page. And it couldn't find your anchor when it loads the page.

To work around this, just add in the lifecycle of your SPA (`useEffect` in React and `mounted` in Vue) some lines to check the url hash and do the scrolling yourself.

example using React

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    if(document.location.hash === '#some-anchor') {
      setTimeout(()=> {
          document
            .querySelector("#some-anchor")
            .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" })
      }, 300)
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: We're wondering if our instance of AEM 6.5 is behaving the same way. We're suddenly unable to use URLs with anchors.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem as well (same page navigation using links) and the solution was very easy (though frustrating to figure out). I hope this helps - also I checked IE, Firefox, and Chrome and it worked across the board (as of 05-22-2019).

Your link should looks like this:

```
<a href="pagename.html##anchorname">Word as link you want people to click</a>
```

and your anchor should look like this:

```
<a name="#anchorname">Spot you want to appear at top of page once link is clicked</a>
```

Comment: my God I spent all day looking for a solution, THANK YOU!!

Comment: Could not get this to work

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for someone who encountered same problem, but scripts didn't work. Try to remove `loading='lazy'` and `decoding='async'` from all images on the page or set `width` and `height` attributes to them.

It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Removing lasy-load solved the issue, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using :
For menu page

```
<li><a href="/explore/##Sound">Sound</a></li>
```

in a menu which appears on all pages

```
<a id="#Sound"><a>
```

This works well in the all versions of Chrome!
I have tested it on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of @Jake_ answer for Chrome / angular not scrolling to a correct anchor on initial page load up using ui-router (the original answer would throw my code into 'Transition superseeded' exceptions):

```
angular.module('myapp').run(function($transitions, $state, $document, $timeout) {
  var finishHook = $transitions.onSuccess({}, function() { // Wait for the complete routing path to settle
    $document.ready(function() { // On DOM ready - check whether we have an anchor and Chrome
      var hash;
      var params;
      var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
      finishHook(); // Deregister the hook; the problem happens only on initial load
      if ('#' in $state.params && isChrome) {
        hash = $state.params['#']; // Save the anchor
        params = _.omit($state.params, ['id', '#']);
        $timeout(function() {
          // Transition to the no-anchor state
          $state.go('.', params, { reload: false, notify: false, location: 'replace' });
          $timeout(function() {
            // Transition back to anchor again
            $state.go('.', _.assign($state.params, { '#': hash }), { reload: false, notify: false, location: 'replace' });
          }, 0);
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  }, {invokeLimit: 1});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps at all or not, but I realized my anchors in IE were working but not in Firefox or Chrome. I ended up adding ## to my anchors and this solved the issue.

example:
a href="##policy">Purpose and Policy Statement

instead of :

a href="#policy">Purpose and Policy Statement

Comment: I tried this and the anchors no longer did anything when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time to find proper solution for this issue.
This is nothing to do with browser version and link itself in my case, but with the fact that page is not fully loaded in Next.js. Hydration on load have not reached my id, that's why it is not on the page and browser does not know it exists. So it is also not able to scroll there.

Easiest solution in my case was to move id="some-id" from section component to index page itself and wrap section component around with div and the same id:

```
      <div id="some-id">
        <Video />
      </div>
```

It works because page component is loading on the page load, but deeply nested components are hydrated later on.

Answer (score -5):

```
 <html>
   <body>
    <li>
      <a href="#Sound">Sound</a>
    </li>
    <a id="Sound" href="www.google.com">I AM CALLED</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

use this as your code it will call the anchor tag with id value sound

Comment: This is what I already have, but was not working due to a bug in chrome specifically, thanks though :)

Answer (score -9):

Simply change the call on your link to external.

```
<a href="#nlink" class="external">  </a>
```