# Adding "#x" to URL doesn't work to automatically scroll down to element when navigating via link

Tags: html, google-chrome, url, scroll, hyperlink

I have a page called "home" with an element with id="element". I have a link on another page that points to this url: "localhost:3000/home#element".

Using Chrome, when I follow the link, it takes me to the home page, but the view isn't scrolled down at all. When I refresh, however, the view automatically scrolls down to #element. It also works when I manually type the URL in.

Why doesn't this work when I'm using a link?

This bug doesn't show up on Firefox.

**Probably unrelated but worth mentioning:** Sometimes, rarely, when I navigate to the url "localhost:3000/home", the page opens already scrolled down to an apparently random position. It happens so sporadically that I haven't had a chance to do much testing on it. I doubt the two bugs are related, though.

Comment: Can help if you show the html code

Comment: @DanteFaña Which one? The link?

Comment: Weird, any relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using)?