# Doxygen generated Html page does not scroll to the destination with hash tag ID

Tags: html, doxygen

I'm using doxygen 1.8.14 to generate document in .html from my C++ source code.

I'm having a problem in my document **only with google chrome**, all other web browsers (FireFox, Opera, Edge,...) are working fine.
In (doxygen-generated) **PageA.html**. I have seveal topics tagged with "#", like:

```
# Topic 1 # {#tag_topic1}
Very lengthy text ...
# Topic 2 # {#tag_topic2}
Very lengthy text ...
# Topic 3 # {#tag_topic3}
Very lengthy text ...
```

In (doxygen-generated) **PageB.html**, I have several links point to those topics defined in **PageA.html**

```
Refer to [topic 1](PageA.html#tag_topic1) ...
Refer to [topic 2](PageA.html#tag_topic2) ...
Refer to [topic 3](PageA.html#tag_topic3) ...
```

When I open **PageB.html** in google chrome browser and click the links, the page navigates to **PageA.html** but does not scroll to the destination topic tagged with "#", it only gives a very quick flashing. 
When test it in all other web browsers, it opens the  **PageA.html** and then smoothly scrolls to the desintation topic and also make a short "glowing effect" on the topic text.

How can I fix this problem for google chrome? 
Appreciate it for any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: You wrote you are using 1.8.4 is this a typo? When not please try version 1.8.14.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo, I'm using 1.8.14.

Comment: Googled for: chrome scroll to tag in page and got (a.o.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using maybe this gives a clue (I didn't test), you probably have to overrule the standard doxygen header (see documentation HTML_HEADER).

Comment: Thank you albert, it worked for me! You have solved a headache for me.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Upon another developer's suggestion, I have solved the problem by adding the following code on every pages, which fixes the Chrome's scrolling problem.
The original code is in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if (window.location.hash && isChrome) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                window.location.hash = "";
                window.location.hash = hash;
            }, 300);
        }
    });
```