# Anchor links not working on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, google-chrome

https://forloop.com.au

The links on the nav bar are mostly anchor links that scroll to anchor tags on the wordpress template.

They are all seem to work on firefox and safari, however chrome seems to not like them.

I've tried updated the jquery scripts (as far as i know they're up to date), and enforced https across the site.

Can anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Not seeing any issues with them on Chrome either.

Comment: same for me.... its working...

Comment: what code are you using to scroll the page?

Answer (score 1):

Please add below code in your JavaScript file:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.menu-item a', function(event) {
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    //checking if # tag available!
    if(url.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url =  url.split('#')[1];
       //calculationg sticky nav height to remove it from scroll length!
        var stickyNavHeight = jQuery('nav.clearfix').height();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery('#'+url).offset().top - stickyNavHeight
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this solves the issue but adds a slight delay on safari when clicking the scroll links.

Comment: Thanks for this. Adding this in console immediately made the page snap to the correct div, which is what we want, but we have to figure out what caused it to quit working for us in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    if (window.location.hash && isChrome) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            window.location.hash = "";
            window.location.hash = hash;
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

This Question is related to previous question. [Anchor <a> tags not working in chrome when using #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using)

Please refer this link

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to scroll the page to position.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.menu-item a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    //var target = "#" + this.getAttribute('data-target');
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('#'+url).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Your code is blocking other urls! Try clicking on CAREERS on this page https://articles.forloop.com.au/