# Internal links doesn't work when I change their color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I need you help
I have a strange error on my code.

The issue is that the internal links to "home" and the one to "footer" doesn't work, whereas the others work fine.
But when I delete the color: #ffffff from .menu a in the css, then they all work.
I don't see how I can solve this issue
Does anyone has an idea ?

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*menu fixe*/
.menu{
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 bottom:60vh;
 z-index: 10;
}

.menu ul{
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.menu li{
 padding: 10px;
}

.menu a{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.menu a:hover{
 background-color: black;
}

/*main content*/
.wrapper{
 width: 60%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/*header*/
.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 top: 0;
 background-color: #D4726A;
 position: sticky;
 z-index: -1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}

/*boxes-all*/
.box-container {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
}
.box-header{
 height: 40vh;
 width: 100vw;
 position: sticky;
 top: 1px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: lightblue;
}

.box-content{
 height: 60vh;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: grey;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}

/*boxes-each*/

.box-header-first{
 background-color: #447684;
}
.box-content-first{
 background-color: #0F414F;
}

.box-header-second{
 background-color: #51A35F;
}
.box-content-second{
 background-color: #10621E;
}

.box-header-third{
 background-color: #67989A;
}
.box-content-third{
 background-color: #0D4A4D;
}

/*footer*/
.footer{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 bottom:0;
 position: sticky;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: -2;
 background-color: #D4A06A;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <!-- En-tête de la page -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>titre</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sticky.css">
    </head>

    <body>
   
    <div class="body">
 <!-- menu fixe -->
    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#boxone">box one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#boxtwo">box two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#boxthree">box three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#footer">footer</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
    </div>

 <!-- contenu -->
    <div class="container">
       
    <!-- main content -->
        <div class="sticky">

        <!-- header -->
            <div class="header" id="home">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
                   </div> 
            </div>

        <!-- boxes -->
            <div class="box-container" id="boxone">
                <div class="box-header box-header-first">
                   <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
                   </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="box-content box-content-first">
                   <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
                   </div> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-container" id="boxtwo"> 
                <div class="box-header box-header-second">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
                   </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="box-content box-content-second">
                   <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
                   </div> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box-container" id="boxthree">
                <div class="box-header box-header-third">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
                   </div> 
                </div> 
                <div class="box-content box-content-third">
                   <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
                   </div> 
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    <!-- footer -->
        <div class="footer" id="footer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <p>Emensis itaque difficultatibus multis et nive obrutis callibus plurimis ubi prope Rauracum ventum est ad supercilia fluminis Rheni, resistente multitudine Alamanna pontem suspendere navium conpage Romani vi nimia vetabantur ritu grandinis undique convolantibus telis, et cum id inpossibile videretur, imperator cogitationibus magnis attonitus, quid capesseret ambigebat.</p> 
            </div> 
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please post the code here.

Comment: I edited my post :)

Comment: It also seems a Chrome/Firefox problem. Because works fine for Safari and Edge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anchor <a> tags not working in chrome when using #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using)

Comment: Thanks. Someone found how to solve the issue easily :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple issue,

Please remove

> top: 0;

property from your `.header` class.

and :

> bottom: 0;

property from your `.footer` class, too.

or copy paste this style instead of your `.header` syle

```
/*header*/
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #D4726A;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You’re welcome, ask any questions related HTML, CSS, PHP to me, I always ready to help anyone.

Comment: and the footer should remove `bottom: 0` also :)

Comment: You did the great job @Kai

Comment: Quick follow up.I noticed something. I corrected the code and the links work fine. But that sliding effect over the header and the footer doesn't work anymore.