# Why the links from the website don't work on the id?

Tags: html, css

today I saw that on my website:
http://teamrefresh.cf/

The nav buttons work on pc, but on my phone don't work, same for the button that get you up. I saw that in Puffin browser works, but on Chrome don't. What I made wrong on the links? Is something about my phone or Chrome?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the smallest reproducible code of what is not working. This will help us better answer your question.

Comment: For context, the _reason_ for requiring a [mcve] be included in the question:  What happens when you update your website so that the issue is no longer present?  Or you completely revamp it or remove it?  At that point, this question becomes relatively useless to any newcomers because the external resource it is based on is no longer accessible.  Additionally, requiring individuals to click offsite to view the issue could be a security concern.  For these reasons, it is expected your question contain sufficient information _in the post itself_.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this could be a bug with certain versions of Chrome. There is more insight on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using). To save time, below is the provided workaround using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if (window.location.hash && isChrome) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                window.location.hash = "";
                window.location.hash = hash;
            }, 300);
        }
    });
```

If you want to use vanilla JS instead of jQuery, you can do the following.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if (window.location.hash && isChrome) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                window.location.hash = "";
                window.location.hash = hash;
            }, 300);
        }
    });
```