# Anchors no longer function in Safari and Chrome, but work in Firefox

Tags: html, anchor

Hi. My portfolio nav menu (list items) no longer functions in Safari and Chrome, but works in Firefox. The creator of this template is no longer available for support. Purchased 5 years ago.

Suggestions (for dummies) to make the anchors work are appreciated. BHNTR.com

———

```html
    <div id="main-menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg" id="mobile-menu-button">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                    <div id="logo-container">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/bhntr-logo.svg" alt="bhntr logo"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-10">
                    <nav id="desktop-menu" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about-us">ABOUT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#portfolio">WORK SAMPLES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

————

Comment: a hrefs are good, can you tell what is problem is related to design, functionality?

Comment: maybe a bug in chrome.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using)

Comment: The bug work around WORKED. Thanks a bunch!