# HTML Anchor doesn't jump to section with url

Tags: html, reactjs, anchor

I have a blog-site, which is full of text, therefore i use sections.

my code:

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>

....

 <h3 id="test">Test</h3>
```

When I click on the anchor, it works, but if I use the URL, i cannot get to the section, only to the top of the site.

What I want:

mysite.com/site1:
`<a href="/site2#test > Test</a>`

mysite.com/site2
`<h3 id="test"> Test </h3>`

Why does it not jump to the section?

Comment: it works on firefox, not in chrome

Comment: Does the element with the matching ID (`test`) exist at load time? If there's any delay rendering elements it's possible browsers might be looking for that element before it's on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using two `#` for the anchor?

```
<a href="/site2##test>Test</a>
```

It seems Chrome sometimes has it's issues with anchor links and this may help (at least works on my machine)

(possibly related to [Anchor <a> tags not working in chrome when using #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588346/anchor-a-tags-not-working-in-chrome-when-using))

Comment: soo, i was typing ##, nothing happend- i removed one # and it worked. I tried one # again, and nothing happend. So i have to type ##, then remove one #, then it works. wtf :-D

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this might be using `window.location` in javascript

```
<script>
        function goToSite2Section() {
            window.location = '/site2#test';
        }
</script>
```

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToSite2Section()"> Test</a>
```